# Changing import in java to substituiting in a * makes it not work

Tags: java

I am trying to more or less master Java without endless crutch leaning on IDE's, so I am doing this in command line mode in win 7... To be sure what's happening. These two source .java's work, then I make a change in the import line and then get an error (NO WORKIE THEN !!!). Here's the two pieces of code when it works to start, then the two lines to 'run it', then what doesn't work.

The essence of it is import "thing.name;" differs from "import thing.*;"
I thought the point of the wild card char is to enable exactly this

```
/** A class to test the CashRegister class */
import animals.CashRegister;
public class ImaMain
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      CashRegister register = new CashRegister();
      register.recordPurchase(29.50);
      register.recordPurchase(9.25);
      register.enterPayment(50);
      double change = register.giveChange();
      System.out.println(change);      
   }
}
```

Thats the main runnable part. Here's the class it uses in a different file named: CashRegister.java makes CashRegister.class

```
package animals;
/**
   A cash register totals up sales and computes change due.
*/
public class CashRegister 
{

   public CashRegister()
   {
      purchase = 0;
      payment = 0;
   }

   public void recordPurchase(double amount)
   {
      double total = purchase + amount;
      purchase = total;
   }

   public void enterPayment(double amount)
   {
      payment = amount;
   }

   public double giveChange()
   {   
      double change = payment - purchase;
      purchase = 0;
      payment = 0;
      return change;
   }
   private double purchase;
   private double payment;
}
```

I prepare it with

```
javac *.java
```

its happy, I copy the created .class file into subdirectory: 'animals', under it, go back up a level and run it:

```
java ImaMain
11.25
```

11.25 is the answer. Perfect right ?
I erase the parellel level .class so its finding the class file where I expect, in subdir: animals

Now I change this line in main to prepare for way more complex stuffola, to:

```
/** A class to test the CashRegister class */
import animals.*;
public class ImaMain
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      CashRegister register = new CashRegister();
      register.recordPurchase(29.50);
      register.recordPurchase(9.25);
      register.enterPayment(50);
      double change = register.giveChange();
      System.out.println(change);      
   }
}
```

One line change. From `import animals.CashRegister;`
                   -to-
                                     `import animals.*;`

javac then generates this error:

```
bad class file: .\CashRegister.class
class file contains wrong class: animals.CashRegister
1 error
```

Doesn't even get to the virtual run step.

The main part file is named: ImaMain.java

I do copy the .class file where it goes. I mean, it does work when the import is more explicit.

```
classpath = .;C:\java\jdk1.7.0_05\lib
```

Comment: It's not clear where the files actually live, or where they were compiled from. Either way, there's a mismatch.

Comment: /** A class to test the CashRegister class */
    import animals.*;
    public class ImaMain
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          CashRegister register = new CashRegister();
          register.recordPurchase(29.50);
          register.recordPurchase(9.25);
          register.enterPayment(50);
          double change = register.giveChange();
          System.out.println(change);      
       }
    }

Comment: ImaMain.java is in a subdir C:\temp_72

Comment: CashRegister.class is in c:\temp_72\animals both .java started in c:\temp_72

Answer (score 2):

Either you called `java` when you were in the subdirectory animals or you moved the `CashRegister.class` file up.

This has nothing to do with changing the import line.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make sense based on your explanation, but this error:

> bad class file: .\CashRegister.class 
>   class file contains wrong class: animals.CashRegister 
>   1 error

Makes it look like the directory structure is incorrect.  This file has to be in a subdirectory like this:

`.\animals\CashRegister`

Use the `dir` or `ls` directory listing tool to verify that the path relative to your `javac -cp . <dirs>` command is correct.

Answer (score 1):

> I copy the created .class file into subdirectory: 'animals'

Yes, but you left the original in the directory you started in. Now there are two CashRegister.class files, one in the top-level directory and one in subdirectory animals. When you run `javac` again it sees that there is a CashRegister.class file present but it contains a class named `animals.CashRegister` which should be in `animals/CashRegister.class`.

You can compile CashRegister with the `-d` flag to `javac` which will tell it where to put the generated `.class` files. That way, you won't have to manually copy the files yourself into the subdirectory.

> `javac -d . CashRegister.java`

That should put the CashRegister.class file in an `animals` directory under the current directory.

Comment: Thank You, Mr.Dave Conrad           the -d really helps greatly.

Comment: I'm still confused, but at a higher level of abstraction, sd that's all one gets out of the universe these days. The -d really helps, rmeoves some disorder totally. thank you again

Comment: Sometimes the goal is just to get confused at a higher and higher level of abstraction, until that level gets above the level of the practical thing you want to do.